# Which word to use to introduce reason or justification of a requirement or recomendation

Tags: word-request

When writing technical documents and different "guides", sometimes you need to explain or simply mention a reason or justification of a particular requirement or recommendation. Which word would you use as a "label" for such explanations? An example:

> Maximum number of characters per line: 72 or 78.
>
> **Reason:** This is exactly a line of 6 or 6.5 inches if using a 12-pitch font.

The word "reason" is used as an example, I'm not sure it really works here, and I'm not sure it will work good in a broader set of cases. Maybe "reasoning" or something different? I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: If you are looking for a noun, then possibly rationale, or explanation?

Comment: Rationale is definitely common, e.g. "standards, especially those intended to support critical applications, should define explicitly both the properties expected to accrue from use of the standard and an explicit rationale that justifies the contents of the standard." [Here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-45477-1_4).

Comment: [work well, not good] Reason works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## rationale

Merriam-Webster defines it:

> **1 :** an explanation of controlling principles of opinion, belief, practice, or phenomena

In this context, you are giving an explanation of the controlling phenomenon, which is the length of a line of text.

This term is quite common when something like a guiding principle requires a rational basis and we anticipate this basis will not be readily clear.